# LateInitializationError: Field 'progress' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

I got Error LateInitializationError: Field 'progress' has not been initialized.

```
class _PrintState extends State<Print> {
      late File selectedfile;
      late Response response;
      late String progress;
      Dio dio = new Dio();
    setState(() {
              progress = "$sent" +
                  " Bytes of " "$total Bytes - " +
                  percentage +
                  " % uploaded";
              //update the progress
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the line

```
late String progress;
```

with

```
String progress = '';
```

or

```
late String progress = '';
```